# Inno Setup: How to capture Exit code in [Files] section

Tags: inno-setup

1)I have installed 1.0 version product.

2)When am trying to upgrade the product to 2.0 version, then am facing the below problems:

a)when the files are in use innosetup throws an error saying it cannot replace the files and shows abort retry ignore message box.

So my requirement is, when innosetup is unable to replace the file in silent/interactive installation i need to know the  exit status of it, so that i can try to rename the file(which is in use) and retry copying the file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to do that.

You can use the `restartreplace` flag to schedule the file to be replaced on reboot if it is in use during the install.

But a better solution is to prevent it from being in use in the first place, eg. by using `AppMutex` to detect that your application is running, or by shutting down a background application/service, or by using the latest version of Inno combined with Restart Manager support in your background app.

Comment: We are already using restartreplace flag. If binary is having any file handles, restartreplace flag replaces the binary after reboot the machine. My requirement is detect if any file handles on binary, then rename the old binary during [files] section.

Comment: >But a better solution is to prevent it from being in use in the first place, eg. by using AppMutex to detect that your application is running,                                                            
We have almost 40 binaries in [files] section, if use teh mutex concept then we need to add all the mutex names in 
"AppMutex" settings in [SETUP] section, which will take lot of time and effort.

Comment: >by shutting down a background application/service,

For shuting down teh background application/service which is using our binary, at first place we need to detect which app is using our binary.
For that we are unable to find a software or api which does that.

>by using the latest version of Inno combined with Restart Manager support in your background app.

what is this? can you explain?

Comment: "Taking a lot of time and effort" is not a valid reason to avoid doing something if it is a requirement for correct operation.  And note that DLL files do not count, only EXE files do, because it's the running processes that matter.  A single installer should typically not have that many EXE files, because it is supposed to be for one application.

Comment: Regarding Restart Manager, mostly it's just a matter of using the latest version of Inno.  You can optionally choose to [implement restart support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc948909.aspx) in your application, but this is not required for standard applications.

Comment: we use restartreplace flag for other files which we package in the installer, but we have removed that flag for drivers.
the reason is , our product  driver gets loaded before the restartreplace  flag gets loaded, so user has to reboot twice to get the new driver.
can we get rid of this issue using install shield? or its the windows problem?

Comment: Drivers are loaded on boot (except for USB devices that are not currently inserted), which is of course before Windows processes the `restartreplace` entries.  This would be an issue with any install system.  Typically you need to use special APIs to install or upgrade drivers; they don't work the same way as other files.  You should ask this sort of thing as a separate question.